# Mysql table update same company_id

Tags: mysql

I have a table. I want to assign numbers between 1 and 24 in the image column in my table. However, while doing this, I want the company_id to increase in the same order.

For example, if there are 2 records in the table with company_id =100, I want the first record to be assigned a value of 1 and the second record to be assigned a value of 2.

Then, when I switch to the record with company_id=101, I want it to start from 1 again.

How can I write this query for mysql database?

Comment: ```company_id + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY company_id) - 1```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out..  I created this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_data2` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `image_path` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

With data:

```
    id  company_id  image_path
------  ----------  ------------
     1         100  img_100_a
     2         100  img_100_b
     3         100  img_100_c
     4         100  img_100_d
     5         101  img_101_a
     6         101  img_101_b
```

And the following query:

```
SELECT id, company_id, image_path,
    (
        CASE company_id 
        WHEN @cur_company_id
        THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
        ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @cur_company_id := company_id
        END
    ) AS company_image_counter
FROM test_data2
ORDER BY company_id
```

Gives the output:

```
    id  company_id  image_path  company_image_counter
------  ----------  ----------  -----------------------
     1         100  img_100_a                         1
     2         100  img_100_b                         2
     3         100  img_100_c                         3
     4         100  img_100_d                         4
     5         101  img_101_a                         1
     6         101  img_101_b                         2
```

So, for company id 100, for 4 images, it gives counter 1 to 4
And for company 101, for 2 images, it gives counter 1 to 2.

Above will run in old MySQL versions too.
If you have MySQL 8+, it has LAG and LEAD functions.
Have to check if those can help here.

UPDATE:
And yes, @Akina's query is better:

```
SELECT id, company_id, image_path, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY company_id) AS company_image_counter
FROM test_data2;

    id  company_id  image_path  company_image_counter  
------  ----------  ----------  -----------------------
     1         100  img_100_a                         1
     2         100  img_100_b                         2
     3         100  img_100_c                         3
     4         100  img_100_d                         4
     5         101  img_101_a                         1
     6         101  img_101_b                         2
```